# NSMutableDictionary path "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Tags: swift, nsmutabledictionary, option-type

I have a simple:

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String 
let dataPath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Images")
let imagesPath = dataPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
var dictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: imagesPath)!
```

And after it gets to the last line it crashes and gives me the ol'

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

The variable `fileName` is declared as `var fileName: String!`

I'm unable to write to the path as well. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another potential issue in addition to gnasher729's suggestion is that the contentsOfFile initializer for NSDictionaries and their subclasses:

> **Return Value:**
>
> An initialized dictionary—which might be different than the original receiver—that contains the dictionary at path, or nil if there is a file error or if the contents of the file are an invalid representation of a dictionary.

So if there is an issue with that dictionary, when you force unwrap it in this line

```
var dictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: imagesPath)!
```

it will crash.

Comment: Yep, I needed to save a file to the location first. So I said if NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: imagesPath)! is nil, save the needed file. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a fileName as String! means it might not contain a String, but you are quite sure it does, and you accept that your app crashes if you use the variable fileName and it doesn't contain a String. That seems to be the case here.

Comment: Didn't OP say it gets to the last line though? Wouldn't that mean `NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: imagesPath)` returned `nil`?

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, the problem is likely to be one of the force unwrapped optionals that you are using. There's a reason why a `!` is sometimes referred to as a `Bang!`. They have a tendency to blow up :) Unwrapping things one at a time and using some `print` statements will help you find out what went wrong:

```
if let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as? String,
    let filePath = filePath {

        println("Determined that both documentsPath and filePath are not nil.")
        let dataPath = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Images")
        let imagesPath = dataPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
        if let dictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: imagesPath) {
            println("Determined that dictionary initialized correctly.")
            // do what you want with dictionary in here. If it is nil
            // you will never make it this far.
        }
    }
```